# Deserializing 400 json objects in an array

Tags: c#, json

I am deserializing json objects in an array. I've successfully done this and it automatically brings up 200 users back.  I want to bring back 400 users instead of 200 but can't find a way to do this.
This is the code I have:

```
var json = Get("https: ... users"); //there's a link in here
List<User> List;
List = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json.Content);
```

Comment: `I've successfully done this and it automatically brings up 200 users back`, this means your get is probably only returning 200 records; there's no limit to what the deserialization does by default, it doesn't pick and choose to how many records it does.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing on JsonConvert.DeserializeObject that limits the result... Have you confered if some of the object's JSON is not correctly?

Answer (score -2):

One way may be to parse the incoming json string and cap it at the number you want.  For example if you know each object begins or ends with something, you can proceed through the string, count how many instances of the object you encounter, then when you reach your limit, delete the rest of the objects (that is remove their representations from the string).  Then, when you have finished, deserialize the string.